# Is constrained auto cast valid?

Tags: c++, auto, c++-concepts, c++23

Since C++20, the constrained `auto` is introduced by:

```cpp
Concept auto identifier = init
```

Which means, for instance:

```cpp
std::integral auto x = 10;
```

is valid.

Also, for new-expressions, concept is allowed to be paired with `auto`:

```cpp
new Concept auto { expr };
// or:
new Concept auto ( expr );
```

`auto{expr}` or `auto(expr)` was introduced in C++23 as roughly equivalent to:

```cpp
auto __temp { expr };
return __temp;
```

Does it mean that `Concept auto { expr }` or `Concept auto ( expr )` is also valid?

The simple use case would be usable in trying to create a decay copy while checking its operations checked by constraint.

Comment: I'm not sure what purpose it would serve. Did you have one in mind, or are perhaps asking because of a syntax pattern?

Comment: "*Does it mean that `Concept auto { expr }` or `Concept auto ( expr )` is also valid?*" [Yes](https://godbolt.org/z/v47Tba7zY).

Comment: I asked the author of P0849R8, and he [said](https://twitter.com/lichray/status/1446743366792740869) it's not valid.

Comment: Maybe you can explain why it is invalid from the perspective of a language lawyer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[[dcl.spec.auto.general]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#general-5) allows only `auto` to be the *simple-type-specifier* of a functional type conversion, even though a constrained *placeholder-type-specifier* can be a *simple-type-specifier* grammatically.